# 10 random words without repetition

Tags: java

I have 20 words in sql database in android
I want to choose 10 random words without repeating and put it in 10 textview if activity is starting
I find this code but it's for numbers only

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new 
ArrayList <Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) 
number.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(number);
```

Comment: So instead of adding number `n`, add the `nth` word. Just don't forget to add a condition to not add a word as long as it's identical to the previous word.

Comment: @AntonH can you add simple example please because I'm new in android studio

Comment: int[] array = new Random().ints(limit, low, high).toArray();

Answer (score 3):

If they are in a SQL database, you can use the query:

```
select word
from t
order by rand()
limit 10;
```

With 20 words, this should have quite reasonable performance.  But if the number of words grows, performance could be an issue.

Comment: Thank you, can you give examples if the words location in string

Answer (score 1):

If you've got XQuery 3.1 you can do

```
random-number-generator()?permute($words)[position()=1 to 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 20  WordField
  FROM TableName
  ORDER By rand()
```